# Which small town is leveled and when in Rivers of London?

Tags: rivers-of-london, lies-sleeping

In Ben Aaronovitch's *Lies Sleeping* (Rivers of London book seven), Peter is on the phone to American FBI agent Kimberly Reynolds early in the book looking for information on a suspect who left the UK for the US.

In the introduction to the phone call, Peter narrates the following:

> We'd been very cautious about our contacts until the previous winter, when Kimberly had been forced to break agency protocol and get my help, or at least advice, long distance. And, in the aftermath, nothing happened. Which is impressive considering the centre of a small town was effectively leveled as a consequence.

I thought I'd read everything in this series, but I'm unable to identify this incident. The text suggests the small town is in the US, but I don't recall reading anything in the Rivers of London series set in the US.

Can anyone supply more detail about the incident referenced, and/or additional reading as a primary source?

Comment: Looks like a [noodle incident](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoodleIncident) - ; http://follypedia.wikia.com/wiki/Kimberley_Reynolds

Comment: @Valorum [No, I will never get over Macho Grande](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airplane_II:_The_Sequel#Plot).

Comment: There are three or four graphic novels as well as the prose novels, have you checked those as well? I believe they are officially in continuity.

Comment: @TripSpace-Parasite and the short stories in the back of some of the hardback versions. I'm tempted to believe it is a noodle incident, like the "Bridge Troll teaching PE in Reading", but it seems like a big one.

Comment: @Jontia Could be! I haven't read all the bonus content, so I can't say.

Comment: Follypedia suggests this is now detailed in *Winter’s Gifts*, released June 2023. Posting as a comment as I have not read this and can't confirm I'm understanding the wiki references correctly.

Comment: @qazmlpok that is a distinct possibility. I think the story does back that up as a turning point of Peter and Reynolds interaction. Though I didn't think it was the centre of town they levelled. I'll grab it off the shelf tonight...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the fictitious town of Eloise in northern Wisconsin.

When *Lies Sleeping* was published this seemed to be a [noodle incident](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoodleIncident), however having just read [*Winter's Gifts*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/67990585-winter-s-gifts), it's likely that this is intended to fill in the story. I can't see that this has been formally confirmed, but the plot does seem consistent with the description in *Lies Sleeping*.

The exploits of the Virginia Gentlemen's Company in London during The Hanging Tree are discussed, so it is set later than that novel.

It is set in January, so fits the reference to 'winter'.

Claiming that the centre of the town was levelled might be a bit of hyperbole, but there is significant property destruction. To be fair to Kimberly and Peter, some of this happened before she got there:

> The building was gone.
>
> Later I found out that the town hall had been a
> one-storey brick building, simple and sturdy. I’ve seen buildings
> levelled by bombs, runaway trucks and what we’re officially calling an
> atypical sinkhole formation. But this one shouted ‘tornado’.

On the other hand, when they do make contact, Peter does advocate for some significant intervention:

> ‘There’s always a single point – a core, if you like,’ he said. ‘If
> you find that and destroy it, preferably with fire, the whole
> malignancy collapses.’
>
> ‘Kill it with fire,’ I said. ‘Right. How much
> fire?’
>
> ‘Do you have access to incendiary grenades?’
>
> Unfortunately the
> DLA’s 1033 Program didn’t stretch that far – so I asked if there was
> an alternative.
>
> ‘An accelerant, and lots of it,’ said Peter. ‘Petrol,
> diesel, whatever you can get. The fire is important – it doesn’t have
> to be fast, it just has to be thorough.’

In the end, she only destroys one building directly:

> Lots of people, from the Bayfield County Sheriff’s Department to
> Wisconsin Emergency Management, all of whom had mobilised vehicles,
> dogsleds and helicopters and had arrived just in time for a single FBI
> agent to blow up Eloise’s emergency centre.